# Can InstallAnywhere Enterprise projects be used with the Standard edition?

Tags: installanywhere

We're upgrading from InstallAnywhere 8.0 Enterprise Edition to InstallAnywhere 2012, but we're considering the 2012 Standard Edition. Can project files generated with v8.0 Enterprise be used with the 2012 Standard Edition without complications? The installer we build basically unpacks files into a user-defined location, generates *.bat files with file paths that are defined by the user during installation, and then runs those *.bat files. The *.bat files contain very basic MySQL commands to create schema (if necessary), modify tables, insert columns, etc. Web searching has not been helpful, and I can't install the 21-day trial version that the vendor recommended we do to uncover any issues. Any advice regarding compatibility issues when going from the Enterprise edition to the Standard edition is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If you peek into an InstallAnywhere project file, you'll see a bunch of deeply-nested XML elements that define a large number of fully qualified class names (FQCNs). It seems like InstallAnywhere is a giant reflection engine that reads this XML and instantiates the Swing components defined in the XML.

Depending how InstallAnywhere Standard Edition is constructed (in other words, are ALL InstallAnywhere classes shipped, but disabled, or is just a subset of InstallAnywhere classes shipped) and on whether or not your installer uses any Enterprise-only features, loading an Enterprise Edition project into the Standard Edition editor may, or may not, cause InstallAnywhere to barf all over itself.

My *speculation* is that if you've avoided any actions and rules that are Enterprise-only, then your file will *probably* load successfully in Standard Edition. However, if your project includes Enterprise-only features (aka, Enterprise-only FQCNs), then it will probably barf.

In reality, the only way to find out for sure is to just try it. Install a trial of Standard Edition and give it a whirl. You could do the installation on a Virtual Machine if you don't want to affect your current Enterprise Edition installation. When you're done, throw away the VM.

If you're adamantly opposed to installing Standard Edition and doing an empirical test, then you'll have to review your installer in the Advanced Editor and compare the features you use to the features outlined in the docs. The InstallAnywhere docs indicate which features are Enterprise-only. If you use any of those, you should expect that your installer will not function under Standard Edition. You may be able to replace the Enterprise-only features with other Standard Edition alternatives, or with scripting.